# Spark insert overwrite into dynamic partition table not working as expected

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata, hiveql

I trying to merge a lot of small files generated into a bigger one. My files are in parquet format.
I am creating a new temp table (external table) at a new location and then overwriting it with the old one.
The files in the new table location gets perfectly merged if I do this with HiveSQL CLI (I get only one file per partition)... But when I try to do this via Spark SQL (running the same Hive commands) I am not getting the files merged but instead as previously they were there in the old location.
I've set the confs

```
sqlContext.setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
sqlContext.setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")

sqlContext.sql("INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE <newtable> PARTITION (<partition_cols>) SELECT * FROM <oldtable>")
```

Please help!!

P.S.:- I am using Spark 1.6.0

Comment: See this answer to [Add column in hive not allowed from scala/spark code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50758947/8371915)

Comment: But its not like I am altering the table schema........ just doing an overwrite/insert. Is this also not allowed?

Comment: Can you tell something in "spark" way.... Using pure spark APIs to insert data into tables.